# Add script in angular-cli project

Tags: angular

How do I add a script file in the index file in an `angular2` project created with `angular-cli` :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CourseTests</title>
    <base href="/">

    {{#unless environment.production}}
    <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {{/unless}}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<course-tests-app>Loading...</course-tests-app>


{{#each scripts.polyfills}}
<script src="{{.}}"></script>
{{/each}}
<script>
    System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
    }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

For example , how do I add angular2's http script?

It would also be very much appreciated if someone explains how this block of code works:

```
{{#unless environment.production}}
    <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {{/unless}}
```

Comment: yes , I am sure, it's angular-cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index.html` file should not be modified.

There are three files you should be editing (it should get easier as time goes on).

1. `angular-cli-build.js` in `/`
2. `system-config.ts` in `/src/`
3. The component file it's needed in

In the `angular-cli-build.js`, add the file path (excluding `node_modules`) to the `vendorNpmFiles` array.

In `system-config.ts`, use the `map` object to alias your file, and `packages` to define the type of module it is (`global`, `cjs`, etc), the main file, and defaultExtension (if needed).

In the file you need it in, simply use the `import` statement and you should be set.

The `@angular/http` is already included for you. To import it, use `import { Http } from '@angular/http';`.

The second part of your question, that is the reload script the cli uses to refresh your page when you are running `ng serve` and you make a change your `.ts` files. It won't be there in production (`ng serve --prod` or `ng build --prod`) due to the `#unless` part.

For the sake of examples, below you can find how to import a `LocalStorage` library called [h5webstorage](https://github.com/SirDarquan/h5webstorage).

`angular-cli-build.js`:

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
  'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
  'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',

  'h5webstorage/**/*.+(js|ts|js.map)'
]
```

`/src/system-config.ts`:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'h5webstorage': 'vendor/h5webstorage'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'h5webstorage': {
    main: 'index.js',
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
};
```

The file you want to use it in.

```
import { LocalStorage, WEB_STORAGE_PROVIDERS } from 'h5webstorage';
```

Comment: How would I change the "polyfills" that are included? i.e. where is the `scripts` variable defined that is used in the tenplate like this `{{#each scripts.polyfills}}`?